# performance of string containing only uppercase letters

Tags: java, string

Here is code to detect a string containing uppercase letters but not sure whether its performs the best. Any improvement would be great help as im applying to huge chuck of data.

```
public static boolean testAllUpperCase(String str){
    for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++){
        char c = str.charAt(i);
        if(c >= 49 && c <= 102) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    //str.charAt(index)
    return true;
}
```

Comment: How are *we* meant to know the interviewer's intention? (I assume this is Java, by the way? You haven't said... or bothered to format your code.)

Comment: You know, you could just run this code and see what happens... Take less time than posting a question and waiting for someone to do it for you.

Comment: It *will* create a new String and leave it's reference in `obj`.  Doing so is pointless, though.  (If you claim to know Java you should know this cold.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. The intent is to test whether the interviewee understands the concept of inheritance in Java- "String is an Object"